# References for the computational complexity of training neural networks

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

I'm looking for a good review paper or book chapter that offers an accessible introduction to the computational complexity of training neural networks for classification problems.

In particular, I'm trying to study questions like:

1. How is training complexity related to network topology ?
2. How is training complexity related to the complexity of the decision boundary?

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85641/references-for-the-computational-complexity-of-training-neural-networks

Comment: @ClementC. I realized only after posting that this SE might be better suited for my question. I can't delete the old post because it already has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the papers by Roi Livni and coauthors:

*Roi Livni, Daniel Carmon, Amir Globerson:
Learning Infinite Layer Networks Without the Kernel Trick. ICML 2017: 2198-2207

*Roi Livni, Shai Shalev-Shwartz, Ohad Shamir:
On the Computational Efficiency of Training Neural Networks. NIPS 2014: 855-863